# Qtip2 A Tooltip With Lots of Data to Display - Would Like to Keep it Out of Source View if Possible (CakePHP, jQuery, Qtip2)

Tags: jquery, tooltip, cakephp-2.0, qtip2

I have a php page which puts X number of planet images on the screen, and then provides a mouseover tooltip for each planet, which will be packed planet-related information. What I'd like to do, if possible, is not clutter up my page source with all the tooltip data. I'd like it to be hidden, somehow.

Here's where I create one of the image tags, complete with the json-encoded array of my planet data (which was placed on the session in my cakePHP Controller object).

```
<?php
    foreach ($game['Planet'] as $planet) {
        echo $this->Html->image('../img/planet/' . $planet['planet_image_file'] .'.png', 
                array('class' => 'planet_img planet_' . $planet['id'], 
                    'id' => 'planet_' . $planet['id'], 
                    'alt' => $planet['planet_name'], 
                    'data-planet' => json_encode(array('planet_name' => $planet['planet_name'],'planet_type' => $planet['planet_type']));
    }

?>
```

(Just two fields at the moment, but there will be about 30 more to come)

Here is my jQuery that creates the Qtip2 tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.planet_img').each(function(){
     $(this).qtip({
         content: $(this).data('planet').planet_name,
         position: {
             my: 'top left',
             at: 'right top'
         }
     });
   })
});
```

So, as you can see, at the moment, I'm just setting the content of the Qtip to be just one of the fields from the planet-info JSON array. Eventually, I'll be constructing a nicely formatted div tag, that contains all the planet data, and CSS styling....

Is there any better way to do any of this? I was thinking about having the Qtip get its content via an Ajax call, but there are going to be thousands of users mousing over thousands of planets, *constantly*, and I can only imagine it will be a huge strain on my MySQL backend.

What about having the Qtip get the info from the session, where I've already stored the planet details, and where the PHP page is getting it from? If that's workable, then I can't currently see how, and need a nudge.

Basically, I'm open to advise and suggestions here, otherwise I'm obviously going to end up doing it the messiest way!

Comment: Use AJAX and have the PHP script use a memory cache.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll look into it. any other possiblities?

Comment: Why are you concerned about cluttering up your page source? Users don't see the page source, so why does it matter?

Assuming " X number of planet images" doesn't refer to a massive number, then there should be no need to ajax. Just get all the data in one query, and put it in hidden div's, or in a data attribute as you've done. This doesn't create a 'cluttered page source' - it's just an effective solution.